# Is it good to continuously do the same workouts for maintaining our musles?

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines

We have changed our workout plan from the past month onward. Our daily workouts are

- back
- squat
- chest
- shoulder
- biceps
- abdomen

in heavy weights. We are doing it for obtaining muscular strength. I have read that rest is needed for 24 hours for small muscles and 48 hours for large muscles. Are we doing the correct workout or do we need to change our workout plan?

Comment: What kind of workouts do you do? Because workouts aren't muscles and doesn't tell us how intensive or how often you do them

Comment: Are you lifting the same weights for each exercise each day or are you progressively increasing the weights you're lifting each day?

Comment: Squat (three sets, ten reps) wight of 63kg ,Flat  Bench press for the chest (three sets, five reps) weight of 60kg, shoulder press (three sets, 10 reps) weight of 30kg, dumbells for biceps each hand 10kg.Also it depends up on each day, some day i used to lifting this weights for day and but some other days lifting low weights that i mentioned here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can sustain a workout at the same volume and intensity every day, then it's not too much, and you'll be able to maintain your strength at the level necessary to perform that workout (any excess strength will eventually start to dwindle however).

If you're having to reduce the weight on certain days, your target workout intensity and volume is exceeding your capacity to be able to do it every day, and you're heading towards overtraining and a burnout if you keep it up. At least one rest day with no exercise should be inserted between each workout, if not two or three, or six. Depending on the intensity and duration of your workout, and your recovery ability, you might take 2-3 days simply to get back to the strength level you were at before, and the next 1-3 days your muscles are actually getting stronger. So 3-6 rest days is optimal for a high intensity workout.

Keep adding rest days until at the very least you can perform each workout at the same intensity and volume. Ideally, however, you can incrementally increase the intensity (weights used) over time. Maybe not each workout, but certainly once every 3 or 4 workouts you should be able to go up 1kg (that's a conservative estimate, especially starting at lower weights you should be able to do a lot more).

If your gains are still pretty slow, then decreasing volume (number of sets, and number of reps in a set) is also advisable, to aid in recovery. If you really want to do more frequent workouts, ie only one rest day between workouts, then cutting back to maximum 2 sets (ideally 1), and maximum 6 reps per set is the other way to go about it.